# replace "+" with space in Nginx side for url created by python quote_plus

Tags: python, nginx, urllib

I write a code with python like this:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

file_name = quote_plus(filename)
```

And my final `url` is something like this http://example.com/name+is+oscar

on server my stored with space "name is oscar"

My webserver in `nginx`, and I want return file when user click on `url` , how to replace "+" with space in `nginx`?!

I saw rewrite can help, but I don't know how work with.